# Using unicode DateTime Patterns (LDML) instead of CultureInfo DateTime Patterns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime-format

I am using a 3rd party product for displaying Data Grids.
This product only supports Unicode LDML DateTime patterns.

.Net CultureInfo uses the Windows DateTime Patterns.

Basically to include AM/PM in the DateTime pattern I need the pattern of "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a" which is the unicode pattern.  But the .Net CultureInfo DateTime pattern is "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt".

I can of course fix this by adding a replace("tt", "a") to the date time pattern but this feels wrong.

There must be a way to output these datetime patterns using the unicode LDML standard.

Regards
Carl

Comment: Does that 3rd party product maybe contain a conversion method?

Comment: I have contacted them but do not have an answer yet.  It is a US company and US datetimes usually include the AM/PM so they must have had this issue before.

Comment: Why not use ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt")